# How to restore data from backintime

Tags: backintime

I crashed my ubuntu installation and reinstalled windows. However I had backintime installed and it took some snapshots which I still have on my HD. I tried to install it on a ubuntu in a virtualbox, but did not see my old snapshots, even when I pointed it to my old snapshot location.

Can someone please help to get my data back?

Answer (score 1):

Old versions of BackInTime (< 1.1.0) where a bit tricky if you want to restore files on a different machine (with different host/user name). Please install the current version from our PPA. This is much more user friendly. It comes with a restore function for the config and won't need to trick the host/user name anymore.

Open a Terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bit-team/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install backintime-qt4
```

Now you can either restore the old config with the `Restore Config` button in Settings or just delete the current config (`rm ~/.config/backintime/config` in Terminal). BackInTime will automatically search for the old config on next start.